# How to run a Svelte app from a subfolder?

Tags: github-pages, svelte, rollupjs

I am hosting a svelte app in GitHub pages, so its served from a subfolder. The problem is that all links aren't working anymore. Basically I need to change the base URL of the app, but I don't know how to do that in svelte or rollup.

**P.S :** I am not using Sapper.

Answer (score 5):

Svelte projects using vite can define a `Public Base Path` either via

- [base config option](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base)
- [command line flag](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#public-base-path)

The flag can be added to the `build` script inside `package.json` to have it set with every `npm run build`

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build --base=/my/public/path/",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
```

Comment: Using the CLI flag, I get a message warning me the setting will be overridden by SvelteKit: `The following Vite config options will be overridden by SvelteKit: -base`

Comment: @SimpleProgrammer With SvelteKit there's the [config.kit.paths.base](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#paths) option. From the docs https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static#github-pages A similar question for SvelteKit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72730192/how-to-host-a-sveltekit-adapter-static-project-on-github-pages

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element for this.

Either set it directly in your *index.html* or use `svelte:head` to set it in the svelte app itself, this allows to easily change it according to development/production

```html
<svelte:head>
  <base href="BASEURL">
</svelte:head>
```

To set it according to the environment you can use something like environment variables and [@rollup/plugin-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-replace) but I feel that is outside the scope of this question. But you can look here [Environment variables in svelte + rollup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62647804/environment-variables-in-svelte-rollup)

Comment: Playing around with the base element it looks like this works with URLs such as `<a href="test"`, but not so much for URLs that start with a slash, `<a href="/test"`.

Comment: If you use a different domain in the base element, URLs that start with a slash will still have their domain changed though.

Comment: I have already used the base element but it's not working, like @wp-overwatch.com said, URLs that start with slash don't change.

Comment: I have the same problem when serving a static site from a nested directory and setting the base element in $layout.svelte AND also setting the base-path in svelte.config.cjs.
I am trying to set relative links to routes like "/about" and "/", and it always sends the user back to the domain-root instead of the app-root,

Answer (score 2):

Svelte-Navigator (Routing)-
You can check here, [https://github.com/mefechoel/svelte-navigator][1]. you can set basepath directly in the Router, then it will read all the URLs with that base path only.

```js
<Router basepath="/base">
    <Link to="profile">Go to /base/profile</Link>
    <Link to="blog">Go to /base/blog</Link>
    <Route path="blog" component={Blog} />
    <Route path="profile" component={Profile} />
</Router>
```

Here "/base" is your subfolder name, for example if your svelte app running at port localhost:5000, by setting base path you can change it to localhost/base

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution, it has caveats but it works.

Only tested when build as a [Single Page Application](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/single-page-apps)

First, edit `svelte.config.js` as follows.

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

export default {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            fallback: 'index.html',
        }),
        paths: {base: '/my-svelte-app'},
    }
};
```

The good thing is that now, every Svelte-generated links are updated with `/my-svelte-app`.

The bad thing is that every human-generated links are NOT updated.
You have to do it manually for every `href` or `src` using the [$app/paths](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-paths) module

```
<script>
    import { base } from '$app/paths';
    export let title = 'Ninja gaming'
</script>


<div class="title">
    <img src="{base}/gamepad.svg" alt="Site logo">
    <h1>{title}</h1>
</div>

<nav class="crumbs">
    <ul>
        <li class="crumb"><a href="{base}/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="crumb"><a href="{base}/guides">Guides</a></li>
        <li class="crumb"><a href="{base}/about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope it helps !