# How to host a SvelteKit (adapter-static) project on GitHub pages?

Tags: github-pages, sveltekit

I would like to host a SvelteKit project on GitHub pages but apparently I haven't found the right settings yet. I tried

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: null,
            precompress: false
        }),
        appDir: 'app',
        prerender: {
            default: true,
        },
        trailingSlash: 'always',
    }
};

export default config;
```

- The `trailingSlash` option is mentioned by the SvelteKit docs
- Removed `_` from the default `appDir: '_app'` because it was mentioned somewhere that it might cause problems because of jekyll. This step should be unnecessary if an empty `.nojekyll` file is added to the project (not sure if to the absolute root of the project or in the folder that's hosted) Either way I saw no difference

When running `preview` after building everything looks fine. But when opening the deployed page all the `.css` and `.js` files have a `404` status. Which setting am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

Since the project hosted on GitHub pages will be served from a url like this `https://{org}.github.io/{repo}` a `base path` must be added and a config like this

```js
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: null,
            precompress: false
        }),
        prerender: {
            default: true,
        },
        trailingSlash: 'always',
        paths: {
            base: '/repo_name'
        }
    }
};
```

plus the empty `.nojekyll` file sitting in the hosted directory should work.

Unfortunately there currently seem to be some problems when having a `base path`

- https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2958
- https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/3752
- https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/4528

first when running `dev` mode, so only set the base path when building like this

```js
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

const config = {
    kit: {
        ...
        paths: {
            base: dev ? '' : '/repo_name',
        }
    }
};
```

And for the errors when buidling there's this workaround for the links

```
<script>
import { base } from '$app/paths';
</script>

<a href="{base}/route">Route</a>
```

With these adjustments `dev` and `build` mode should run and hosting on GitHub pages be possible. `preview` mode still seems to be broken (or is this expected/normal that serving the build locally just can't work because of the base path..?)